# Car Chase SFX Library Recommendation

Tags: car, chase, library, recommendations

I am cutting a Car Chase scene for a student, spec commercial.  All of the libraries I look at only have SFX for doors and car drive bys, etc.  There wasn't a budget for on set recording/ or wild sounds, so I need to know where to find sounds of cars driving, from inside the car, driving with the car, etc.  Can anyone recommend a library that has these types of sounds?

The edit is complete and now I need to sound design the whole thing from scratch.  It's only 15 seconds of material.

The car is an Audi R8.

Answer (score 1):

The Audi R8 and Lamborghini Gallardo share the same engine. You wouldn't be able to tell the difference. The Chevy Camaro sound in Transformers 2 I believe, was actually a Pontiac GTO.

Answer (score 0):

On sale right now. 50% off . No audis though.
http://sounddogs.com/sound-effects-library/2744.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try Boom Library's car set - has a workup of an Audi A3 an a V6 Audi A5 TDI.  While the onboard recordings are not very long like those in Soundstorm or 5000 series, they're nice a clean.  The source material should be more than enough to get the job done.  There's some other good gems in there too (like the BMW 116i car doors).

Also, as mentioned on here, don't be too married to the exact car.  The fact this set has two Audis though should get you 'close enough' in my opinion even though you're not using the exact R8 engine.

Answer (score 0):

try [pole.se](http://www.pole.se). The owner of the company Max is a really nice guy so if you tell him your predicament he may well help you out.